# How to use a mysql stored procedure result set in another stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to filter the result set returned by a stored procedure in side another stored procedure

Ex:

```
delimiter //
create procedure x()
begin
select 1 as a, 2 as b,3 as c;
end //
```

In y stored procedure I want to select only 'a' column value return from 'x' stored procedure

```
delimiter //
create procedure y()
begin

end//
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help.

First get result from proc `x` into a temporary table `tmp`:

```
            delimiter //
            create procedure x()
            begin
            create temporary table `tmp`
            select 1 as a, 2 as b,3 as c;
            end //
```

then call proc `x` into proc `y`

```
            delimiter //
            create procedure y()
            begin
            call x();
            select a from tmp;
            end //
```

Finally call y() to result the field a from proc `x` select .

If you want to get only proc `x` result then run:

```
            call x();
            select * from tmp;
```

Comment: is it possible without create 'tmp' table